# cypress get not querying the new dom after rerender

Tags: javascript, html, cypress

I want to use `cy.get` to query the new DOM after the re-render. But the DOM is updated but cypress seems to cached the DOM on the initial load. The `cy.get` still returning the element in the first load not the update element after the re-render.

Is there away to force `cy.get` to query the new DOM. `cy.get` only picked up the correct value after `cy.reload(true);` But this is not what the user would do. Since the user don't need to reload the page to seem the change.

Here is an example

```
// first load
<div id='first-name'>
 John Smith
</div>
```

```
// after 10 seconds
<div id='first-name'>
 Grace Smith
</div>
```

So `cy.get('#first-name')` should have the text `John Smith` after 10 seconds `cy.get('#first-name')` should have the text `Grace Smith`

```
        cy.get('[data-testid=slot1-text] > tspan').then(text => {
            expect(text.text()).equal('PARKINGFRESERVED');
        });
        cy.get('[data-testid=slot1-text] > tspan:last-child').then(text => {
            cy.wrap(text).should('have.class', 'parking-status-reserved');
            expect(text.text()).equal('RESERVED');
        });

        cy.server();
        cy.route('GET', '/mocks/parkingLotConfigs.json', parkingLotConfigsMock).as(
            'parkingLotConfigs'
        );

        // @TODO remove reload, when there is a better way.
        // Without using reload the page is updated because of pooling. But cypress does not
        // pick up the change in the re-rendered DOM. reload is used as work around only.
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62205766/cypress-get-not-querying-the-new-dom-after-rerender
        cy.reload(true);
        cy.wait('@parkingLotConfigs');

        cy.get('[data-testid=slot1-text] > tspan').then(text => {
            expect(text.text()).equal('PARKINGFRESERVED');
        });
        cy.get('[data-testid=slot1-text] > tspan:last-child').then(text => {
            cy.wrap(text).should('have.class', 'parking-status-reserved');
            expect(text.text()).equal('RESERVED');
        });
```

Comment: Can you post the full test?  How are you waiting in between gets?

Comment: I have posted the working test. Yes I can wait between gets. My app re-renders the page when the polling updates the store. So to mock data change, I changed the response data on the next poll. I can see the page reflecting the new data. But cypress still uses the old DOM.