# Partial refresh in XPages/JSF not available in Cypress

Tags: jsf, cypress, xpages

I use in my XPages/JSF app partial refresh, e.g. when you check a checkbox this element submits data to the server and the server updates the element in the DOM that was specified to become updated.

In my test written in Cypress the to be updated element is not being updated in the browser (chrome).

Is there something I should set / have missed in my interpretation of Cypress capabilities?

I made a most simple type of form with two types of partial refresh: xsp.partialrefreshget (csjs) and partial refresh via the properties control.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.put("switch","on")}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>
    <xp:panel id="pnlAll">
        <xp:button value="On" id="btnOn">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="norefresh">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.put("switch","on")}]]></xp:this.action>
                <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:pnlAll}", {
    onComplete: function() {
        console.log("pnlAll refreshed?")
    }
});]]></xp:this.onComplete>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
        <xp:checkBox text="on" id="cbOn">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="partial" refreshId="pnlAll">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.put("switch","on")}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:checkBox>
        <xp:button value="Off" id="btnOff">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="norefresh">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.put("switch","off")}]]></xp:this.action>
                <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:pnlAll}", {
    onComplete: function() {
        console.log("pnlAll refreshed?")
    }
});]]></xp:this.onComplete>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
        <xp:checkBox text="off" id="cbOff">
            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="partial" refreshId="pnlAll">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.put("switch","off")}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:checkBox>
        <xp:panel id="pnlSwitch">
            <xp:panel tagName="h1" id="offmode">
                Emergency. We are in off mode
                <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.get("switch").equals("off")}]]></xp:this.rendered>
            </xp:panel>
            <xp:panel tagName="h3" id="onmode">
                Chill. We are on.
                <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.get("switch").equals("on")}]]></xp:this.rendered>
            </xp:panel>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

And here is my Cypress code:

```
describe('Partial Refresh', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.fixture('credentials.json').then(user => {
      expect(user.name).to.eq("dummy user")
      expect(user.password).to.eq("dummy password")      

      cy.visit('https://server1.acme.org/names.nsf?logout&redirectto=projectX/patrick/app.nsf/cypress.xsp')
      cy.get('#user-id').type(user.name)
      cy.get('#pw-id').type(user.password)
      cy.get('[type="submit"]').click()
    })   
  })

  it('passes', () => {
    cy.wait(1000)
    cy.get('#view\\:_id1\\:onmode')
   
    cy.get('#view\\:_id1\\:btnOff').click()
    cy.wait(1000)
    cy.get('#view\\:_id1\\:offmode')

    cy.get('#view\\:_id1\\:btnOn').click()
    cy.wait(1000)    
    cy.get('#view\\:_id1\\:onmode')
    
     cy.get('#view\\:_id1\\:cbOff').check()
     cy.wait(1000)    
     cy.get('#view\\:_id1\\:offmode')
     cy.get('#view\\:_id1\\:cbOff').uncheck()
     

     cy.get('#view\\:_id1\\:cbOn').check()
     cy.wait(1000)    
     cy.get('#view\\:_id1\\:onmode')
     cy.get('#view\\:_id1\\:cbOn').uncheck()

     cy.get('#view\\:_id1\\:btnOff').click()
     cy.get('#view\\:_id1\\:offmode')
  })
 
})
```

"Ofcourse" this simple form seems to pass the test without any disturbance though I notice in the console warnings:

> MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak
> detected. 11 runner:next listeners added. Use
> emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

The form that I have in Production is very large, I use several web plugins like select2, bootstrap file upload etc. Perhaps there is just too much overload/items that Cypress has a problem with?

Comment: Without code sample that’s anyone’s guess

Comment: The ordinary dojo/jquery amd loading problem? Or that Cypress is hijacking the event?

Comment: @stwissel what would a code sample provide for value? what the server responds back should not be a discussion. it's even visually noticeable in the cypress app that partial updates do not become available. not sure if the cloud based version solves the issue.

Comment: @FredrikNorling new/updated DOM after render seems to be a common issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62205766/cypress-get-not-querying-the-new-dom-after-rerender

Comment: Code samples allow the reproduction of the issue. SO 101: provide a reproducer

Comment: @stwissel example provided, but this is not the code that I have in Production that I am writing tests against, that would be too much to post here (too hard to reproduce to a working sample)